# Enabling index signature for subtypes

Tags: typescript

I have a base type that looks like this:

```
export abstract class ElementBase extends HTMLElement {

    private state: StateBase;
    private propertyToWatch: string;

    update() {
        const externalValue = this.state[this.propertyToWatch]; // <- this doesn't compile
        // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'StateBase'.
        this.updateUI(externalValue);
    }
...
```

`StateBase` is a class with two methods, but importantly it is inherited by a bunch of other classes that have properties like `pageNumber: number;`. As noted at the comment, I can't access the property of the subclass by named index, since TypeScript v5.x deprecated the `suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors` config switch. The [guidance](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51909) says:

> Fix: Add an index signature to the relevant type (or use a type assertion at the indexing location).

I can't seem to figure out how to apply this though to a subtype that I don't know at runtime. If I add an index signature to `StateBase`, it breaks the methods and properties of the base type and its inheritors. And a type assertion doesn't seem possible if I'm using subtypes. What am I missing?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing without unrelated problems.  At least a toy definition of `StateBase` would be helpful, and any other problems (like missing `updateUI` or uninitialized `propertyToWatch`) should be cleared up.  That way we can get to work on the problem you do have without being needing to either work around or ignore the ones you don't.

Comment: @jcalz I appreciate what you're asking, but the question is academic, not about the specific implementation. Typescript, for type safety, doesn't want you to access properties by indexer (which plain JS allows), but the guidance doesn't give meaningful feedback about what to do instead.

Comment: Oh well, maybe someone else will be able to help without a [mre].  Good luck!

Comment: Use `class ElementBase<B extends StateBase>{ state: B, propertyToWatch: keyof B }`

Comment: @Dimava can you post that in an answer with a little more context, please? Happy to give you the credit, this is the answer I was looking for. I just needed to set `externalValue` with `this.state[this.propertyToWatch as keyof B]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @Dimava in the comment, but here's the solution. As I mentioned, Typescript doesn't like accessing properties by way of named indexes, because of type safety. You can still hit those properties with the `keyof` syntax. I just wasn't sure how to apply that if you were using a subtype, not knowing the concrete type at runtime, but I forgot generics are a thing in TS. My original example changes to look like this:

```
export abstract class ElementBase<B extends StateBase> extends HTMLElement {

    private state: B; // use the generic type here
    private propertyToWatch: string;

    update() {
        const externalValue = this.state[this.propertyToWatch as keyof B]; // <- access the property with keyof
        this.updateUI(externalValue);
    }
...
```

You have to change the class declaration to include the generic. Then I needed to reference the subtype, generic `B` instead of `StateBase`. The trick is that all of the subtypes of this new `ElementBase` have to declare the `StateBase` derivative, which was not a big deal.

I kind of wish they would have left the override config flag for this, but whatever. For the extra curious, this was used in sort of an observable pattern, where components should update some UI when the value on a state property changed. I know there are libraries for this, but I didn't want to add all of that for the relatively small scope involved.